# Vector contains data but reports length is 0, can be accessed by some functions

Tags: vector, rust, borrow-checker, fits, rust-bindgen

I've written a wrapper for a camera library in Rust that commands and operates a camera, and also saves an image to file using bindgen. Once I command an exposure to start (basically telling the camera to take an image), I can grab the image using a function of the form:

```
pub fn GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(
handle: *mut qhyccd_handle,
w: *mut u32,
...,
imgdata: &mut [u8],) -> u32 //(u32 is a retval)
```

In C++, this function was:

```
uint32_t STDCALL GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(qhyccd_handle: *handle, ..., uint8_t *imgdata)
```

In C++, I could pass in a buffer of the form `imgdata = new unsigned char[length_buffer]` and the function would fill the buffer with image data from the camera.

In Rust, similarly, I can pass in a buffer in the form of a Vec: `let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(length_buffer)`.

Currently, the way I have structured the code is that there is a main struct, with settings such as the width and height of image, the camera handle, and others, including the image buffer. The struct has been initialized as a `mut` as:

```
let mut main_settings = MainSettings {
width: 9600,
...,
buffer: Vec::with_capacity(length_buffer),
}
```

There is a separate function I wrote that takes the main struct as a parameter and calls the GetQHYCCDSingleFrame function:

```
fn grab_image(main_settings: &mut MainSettings) {
let retval = unsafe { GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(main_settings.cam_handle, ..., &mut main_settings.image_buffer) };
}
```

Immediately after calling this function, if I check the length and capacity of main_settings.image_buffer:

```
println!("Elements in buffer are {}, capacity of buffer is {}.", main_settings.image_buffer.len(), main_settings.image_buffer.capacity());
```

I get 0 for length, and the buffer_length as the capacity. Similarly, printing any index such as `main_settings.image_buffer[0]` or 1 leads to a panic exit saying `len is 0`.

This would make me think that the `GetQHYCCDSingleFrame` code is not working properly, however, when I save the image_buffer to file using [`fitsio` and `hdu.write_region` (fitsio docs linked here)](https://docs.rs/fitsio/0.14.1/fitsio/hdu/struct.FitsHdu.html#method.write_region), I use:

```
let ranges = [&(x_start..(x_start + roi_width)), &(y_start..(y_start+roi_height))];
hdu.write_region(&mut fits_file, &ranges, &main_settings.image_buffer).expect("Could not write to fits file");
```

This saves an actual image to file with the right size and is a perfectly fine image (exactly what it would look if I took using the C++ program). However, when I try to print the buffer, for some reason is empty, yet the `hdu.write_region` code is able to access data somehow.

Currently, my (not good) workaround is to create another vector that reads data from the saved file and saves to a buffer, which then has the right number of elements:

```
main_settings.new_buffer = hdu.read_region(&mut fits_file, &ranges).expect("Couldn't read fits file");
```

Why can I not access the original buffer at all, and why does it report length 0, when the `hdu.write_region` function can access data from somewhere? And where exactly is it accessing the data from, and how can correctly I access it as well? I am bit new to borrowing and referencing, so I believe I might be doing something wrong in borrowing/referencing the buffer, or is it something else?

Sorry for the long story, but the details would probably be important for everything here. Thanks!

Comment: errr just looking at the C++ definition GetQHYCCDSingleFrame requires you to pass it a buffer where it will store the length and you would then have to construct your [u8] from the raw information.

Comment: how do you expect vector magically know it have been filled ? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.set_len but I would advice you to use resize that is a less error prone api since you start in rust (use resize before and after the call will avoid you to use unsafe)

Comment: From your question it is a bit unclear whether you understand the difference between a vector's _length_ and _capacity_. By specifying capacity upfront you forced `Vec` to allocate (uninitialized) data. If C++ code is setting data in that buffer without telling Rust, then you need to call `set_len()`, as explained in the previous comment. Or you can just avoid capacity at all, and create a `vec![0u8; length_buffer]`. Then `&mut buffer` will not be empty.

Comment: How does the C++ function know the buffer length ? How does it communicate how much bytes it has written in the buffer ? Use that information to call  `set_len()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, you need to know that `Vec<u8>` and `&mut [u8]` are not quite the same as C or C++'s `uint8_t *`. The main difference is that `Vec<u8>` and `&mut [u8]` have the size of the array or slice saved within themselves, while `uint8_t *` doesn't. The Rust equivalent to C/C++ pointers are raw pointers, like `*mut [u8]`. Raw pointers are safe to build, but requires `unsafe` to be used. However, even tho they are different types, a smart pointer as `&mut [u8]` can be casted to a raw pointer without issue AFAIK.

Secondly, the capacity of a `Vec` is different of its size. Indeed, to have good performances, a `Vec` allocates more memory than you use, to avoid reallocating on each new element added into vector. The length however is the size of the used part. In your case, you ask the `Vec` to allocate a heap space of length `length_buffer`, but you don't tell them to consider any of the allocated space to be used, so the initial length is 0. Since C++ doesn't know about `Vec` and only use a raw pointer, it can't change the length written inside the `Vec`, that stays at 0. Thus the panicking.

To resolve it, I see multiple solutions:

- Changing the `Vec::with_capacity(length_buffer)` into `vec![0; length_buffer]`, explicilty asking to have a length of `length_buffer` from the start
- Using `unsafe` code to explicitly set the length of the `Vec` without touching what is inside (using `Vec::from_raw_parts`). This *might* be faster than the first solution, but I'm not sure.
- Using a `Box<[u8; length_buffer]>`, which is like a `Vec` but without reallocation and with the length that is the capacity
- If your `length_buffer` is constant at compile time, using a `[u8; length_buffer]` would be much more efficient as no allocation is needed, but it comes with downsides, as you probably know

Comment: This helped! Thank you for the background on it, I realized my buffer was initialized with capacity but nothing in it. So changed it to vec![0; length_buffer] and it works perfectly!